# Is it possible to send `postMessage` to an app with Cypress? How to pass data that would be received via `postMessage`?

Tags: browser, automated-tests, e2e-testing, cypress

I'm creating Cypress e2e tests, however our app is opened as a modal (iframe) on top of a parent page. As Cypress does not support iframes I decided to try and run app "standalone". However on start app is getting data from parent page via `window.postMessage` (info about flow and session). Is it possible to pass this data to app via Cypress?

I have tried to get data that we receive from backend via cy.request and it solves problem with session data, however I still can't figure out how to pass information about flow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can send a [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) in Cypress. Because Cypress runs in the browser next to your application, it has access to all web APIs.

In order to get a reference to the `window` object of your application, you can use [`cy.window()`](https://on.cypress.io/window)

Putting it all together, this is how you send a `postMessage` to your application under test:

```js
cy.window() // get a reference to application's `window`
.then($window => {
  const message = 'some data here'
  $window.postMessage(message, '*')
})
```

Answer (score -3):

Sending POST forms when visiting a page is indeed possible. [As of Cypress 3.2.0, you can send POST requests using cy.visit.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#3-2-0)

You can check the [`cy.visit()` docs for more details](https://on.cypress.io/visit), but here is a quick code example of what you're trying to do:

```js
cy.visit({
  url: 'http://my-app.com/standalone-iframe-modal.html',
  method: 'POST',
  body: {
    formKey: 'some-value',
    anotherKey: 'some-other-value'
  }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately it returns "405 Not Allowed" for me.

Comment: @Toronto that's coming from your backend web server, not from Cypress. By default, cy.visit sends the POST with `application/x-www-urlencoded` encoding, is that what your backend is expecting to receive? Or is it expecting `multipart/form-data`, or something else?

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure if I understand or if we are on the same page. Backend is expecting `application/x-www-urlencoded`, however I need to send postMessage to iframe app. Normally this postMessage would be sent by a parent site when iframe app is started (one of few buttons is pressed, then iframe app is started and corresponding flow info in passed to it).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. You just want to `postMessage` to your application being tested? (I thought you meant `POST` message originally :))

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need to dispatch postMessage to app as that's how it gets needed data. Is it possible with Cypress?

Comment: Yes, I'll write another answer once I get into the office :)